# How to hide terminal warning when Oh-my-ZSH plugin can't access external app

Tags: zsh, fzf

I've been using oh-my-zsh for a while and it's working great. I'd like to use the command-line fuzzy finder plugin so I enabled it in .zshrc:

```
plugins=(fzf)
```

However if "fzf" is not installed I get a warning when opening my terminal window:

> [oh-my-zsh] fzf plugin: Cannot find fzf installation directory.
>    Please add `export FZF_BASE=/path/to/fzf/install/dir` to your .zshrc

Is there a way to hide that warning message? When I install fzf with "sudo dnf install fzf" the warning dissapears, but maybe I want to clone my dotfiles on a different computer where it is not available and it's not that important to be there.

Answer (score 3):

you should first install fzf, in Mac and i use the following command to install `brew install fzf`

Comment: yes, that works for my M1 Mac

Answer (score 1):

You need to have fzf installed to use this plugin; otherwise remove it.  It won't do anything without first installing fzf.  Sudo apt install fzf

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `plugins=` line inside an `if` statement that checks for the presence of fzf in your path. For example:

```
if [[ -n $(command -v fzf) ]] ; then
    echo "fzf found, loading oh-my-zsh fzf plugin"
    plugins=(vi-mode fzf)
else
    echo "no fzf was found in the path"
    plugins=(vi-mode)
fi
```

`command -v` is similar to `which`, but is superior for this context as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script). 
The `-n` makes the `[[ ]]` evaluate as true whenever the `$()` produces a non-empty output.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was also very important that `brew` itself was in Path of `~/.zshenv` like so:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Installed FZF with brew on an M1 Mac.

Otherwise, the error occurs:

```
[oh-my-zsh] fzf plugin: Cannot find fzf installation directory.
Please add `export FZF_BASE=/path/to/fzf/install/dir` to your .zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install fzf by using brew, it needs to be set brew env.
You can solve to set PATH for fzf before the line of plugins=(fzf) in .zshrc file.

But, I recommand creating "$HOME/.zprofile" as following.

For m1 Mac.

```
# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

For, intel Mac

```
# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.
eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"
```